# Flutter: Using image instead of icon

Tags: image, flutter, icons

I have a sample code for a radiostream player.
The code provides for an icon to represent its state (paused or playing).
I would like to show an image instead of the icon.

Being a newby/noob with flutter im stuck.
Can sonebody push me in the right direction?

Here is the current code:

```
...........    
default:
                        return Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    print("button press data: " +
                                        snapshot.data.toString());
                                    await _flutterRadioPlayer.playOrPause();
                                  },
                                  icon: snapshot.data ==
                                          FlutterRadioPlayer
                                              .flutter_radio_playing
                                      ? Icon(Icons.pause)
                                      : Icon(Icons.play_arrow))
                            ]);
                        break;
                    }
...............
```

So in short, i want to use an image, "pause.png" for Icons.pause and "play.png" for Icons.play_arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that IconButton thing and use this as a child of Future Builder
and the future builder will return this

```
Image.asset('pause.png'):Image.asset('play.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

the icon is of type Widget so you can pass for example Image.asset([path to asset]) instead Icon()

Answer (score 1):

**here is the example**

```
return Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                            // replace Icon button to this custom button and wrap with Inkwell 
                            children: <Widget>[
                              InkWell(
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    print("button press data: " +
                                        snapshot.data.toString());
                                    await _flutterRadioPlayer.playOrPause();
                                  },
                                  child : snapshot.data ==
                                          FlutterRadioPlayer
                                              .flutter_radio_playing
                                      ? Image.asset("image path")
                                      : Image.asset("image path "))
                            ]);
                        break;
                    }
```